# SQL Merge and large table data

Tags: sql, merge

I will be running a MERGE SQL query to query over a million records in my source table and insert into my target table.  This table that I'm doing the SELECT from in the Merge is in production.  This table will have an application with many users hitting the table for SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE at the same time.  I will NOT be modifying the source table data with my MERGE statement, only the target table.  I will have SQL Snapshot Isolation enabled, so no reason to use NOLOCK hint.  Is there a way to have the query run in batches, or is having the MERGE statement scan the entire table more efficient?  I have 2 other merge statements I'll be running after the initial INSERT to do INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on target table for any changes that were done.  Are there any precautions I need to take so as to not cause performance issues with the production application?  I'm going to use a stored procedure because I will be running these queries on multiple tables that will be doing the same function over and over again.

My sample initial MERGE:

```
MERGE dl178 as TARGET
USING dlsd178 as SOURCE
ON (TARGET.docid = source.docid AND TARGET.objectid = source.objectid AND target.pagenum = source.pagenum
    and target.subpagenum = source.subpagenum
    and target.pagever = source.pagever and target.pathid = source.pathid
    and target.annote = source.annote)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (docid, pagenum, subpagenum, pagever, objectid, pathid, annote, formatid, ftoffset, ftcount)
VALUES (
    source.docid, source.pagenum, source.subpagenum, source.pagever,
    source.objectid, source.pathid,source.annote ,source.formatid ,source.ftoffset, source.ftcount)
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Partition Switching or Change Data Capture?  Sounds like you are trying to start an ongoing ETL process.